# How to run a sequnce of AQL queries in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, foxx, arangodb-foxx

I am a newbie and trying to get going on ArangoDB.I want to run a batch of AQL queries which would be interdependent on each other. I want to do the same things we do in PL-SQL. I tried clubbing two or more queries in one post/get request through FOXX but didn't work. Can someone suggest me a better way to do this? or a tutorial for this?

Comment: it all depends what is your client accessing the database. E.g. we are using Java and the java driver to access arangodb. Then you can use either transaction call or just stack it when writing AQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends what is the client accessing the database.

E.g. we are using Java and the java driver to access ArangoDB. Then either transaction call or AQL query with subsequent AQL queries can be made.

The question is, if the AQL queries are interdependent on each other, why whould you run them in one request? How would you get the results of each one?

Take a look at Gremlin language (it is a Graph language), you would find that it uses WebSockets and result of one query is returned in a binary way through WS... Thus batching such queries wouldn't have any sense. (just a note, ArangoDB also has a provider for the Gremlin API).

I expect, if you are accessing ArangoDB through HTTP. And now you are trying to save http requests. If that is the case I would recommend writing your own API layer, which would expose interface, where you would be able to batch the requests. However the API layer would make 2 calls to Arango (e.g. in parallel), getting the results and somehow merging them to the final output.

Comment: "Java and the Java driver to access ArangoDB" answers my question! I can use it like PL-SQL and have control over data. Thanks!                                                            by interdependent, I meant like some orchestrated sequence on of queries. for eg : For creating a user I need to first insert user detail and also make an insert to map the cars he owns. So here I need to insert user and then map some car ids to that user.

Comment: Hm try to look for transactions. I use transactions when I need to delete a hierarchy of vertices + edges and I want to delete all elements only if it is possible to delete all of them (e.g. because of concurrency access etc..). So if you want to insert a user only if the cars he owns is also successfully inserted, I would pass it as transaction.
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/docs/Drivers/Java/Reference/Database/Transactions.md
Or maybe that is too complex and just handling it in Java could be also fine (for creating I don't use transactions).